# c# check if number is greater then number before and count it

Tags: c#

i have an exercise in simple wihle loop,
in that exercise i need to input 5 numbers in while loop, then check if number is greater then number
before, if yes, count it, else start new if and count if number is smallest then number before..

```
input:      example: 1,2,3,4,5
1. number 
2. number
3. number
4. number
5. number
```

so if i have 5 numbers greater then number before the i count it. (count how many numbers are greater then number before)
if i have numberers smallest then number before count it.(same)
if i the numbers is equal then count it..(same)

the output i know how to do but i dont know to put new input into number in the list..

thanks for help
my current code:

```cs
while (totalcount < 5) {

    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (number == 0 && lastnumber > number) {
        lastnumber = number;
        bigcount++;
    }
    if (number == 0 && number < lastnumber) {
        smallcount++;
    }
    if (number == lastnumber) {
        equalcount++;
    }
    totalcount++;
}
Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + bigcount + " " + "biggers numbers.");
Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + smallcount + " " + "smallest numbers.");
Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + equalcount + " " + "equales numbers.");
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why your code is checking if the input is zero?

Comment: if forgot to mention my start code before the loop:
number;
lastnumber;
totalcaount=0
bigcount=0
smallcount=0
equalcount=0

Comment: Do you allways go back to the very first number in order to find numbers greater/smaller/equal or do you start at the position where you stopped the iteration before? So e.g. if you have 1,2,3,2,1 do you want 1,2,3 for greater numbers, and 3,2,1 for smaller ones, or none for the smaller ones because you reset to the first number which is 1 and which is **greater** than the second one?

Comment: I mean that i need input 5 numbers, so for an example if type 1,2,3,4,5 then there is 5 numbers that are greater, and for smaller for an example 5,4,3,2,1 then 5 smallest numbers,..
But the list is 1,2,2,3,5 then it means if have 3 greater numbers, and 1 equals numbers..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stay faithful to your sample. Basically I removed checking if `number == 0` which made no sense whatsoever, and added an if clause `totalcount > 0` to skip doing operations with the first number, since `lastnumber` wouldn't exist in that scenario.

```
int number, totalcount = 0, lastnumber = 0, bigcount = 0, smallcount = 0, equalcount = 0;

while (totalcount < 5)
{
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (totalcount > 0)
    {
        if (lastnumber < number)
        {
            bigcount++;
        }
        else if (lastnumber > number)
        {
            smallcount++;
        }
        else
        {
            equalcount++;
        }
    }

    totalcount++;
    lastnumber = number;
}

Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + bigcount + " " + "biggers numbers.");
Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + smallcount + " " + "smallest numbers.");
Console.WriteLine("there are" + " " + equalcount + " " + "equales numbers.");
```

Comment: Just so i can understand, why did you checked if lastnumber > 0 ?
Im still trying to understand the basic fundamentals of algoritems

Comment: @Moshiko I checked if `totalcount > 0` because I dont want to compare numbers on the first round of the loop  (because I have received only one number from the input and lastnumber has not been set yet).

Comment: i think i understand it problem is for me sometimes its hard for me to understand the quation so even if i dont understand the quation then i wont be able to solve the problem